# can we have a nested html tag?

Tags: html, xml

I am parsing and html/xml file. I am bit confused with the fact that can we have a nested tag like this.

```
<A a="#" b="#".....<xyz>...</xyz> />
```

If yes can you please point out me the place where I could get information about this.

Comment: i dont think its valid. only attributes come inside the `< >` of a tag. and attributes dont start with `<`

Comment: It's definitely not valid.  It's simply not valid HTML.  It wouldn't be valid XML, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot. Other than the tag name and an optional closing ( `/>` ) the only thing allowed inside of the tag it self are attributes which take the form `key=val`. If you want to have `<` or `>` in a tag's attributes then they need to be encoded as `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Nested tags have to be done like so

```
<root>
   <child></child>
</root>
```

A tag that has a `/>` is called self closing, this means it has no children

Answer (score 0):

It is not “well-formed XML,” i.e. XML at all. A tag cannot contain tags.

In HTML up to and including HTML 4.01, if parsed by the specifications (no browser does this), it would be somewhat different. A tag cannot contain a tag, but the `<` would implicitly close the `a` tag (tag, not element). There would still be an error due to lack of closing `</a>` tag. The characters `/>` would be taken as data characters, not markup.

Comment: Bravo - absolutely correct.  To paraphrase: 1) it's completely illegal.  Both for HTML, and for XML.  But ... 2) pre-HTML 4.01 parsers allowed all kinds of crap.  So it's entirely possible that a browser might actually accept it.